# Django comment moderation, not public

Tags: django, django-models, django-comments

im trying moderation comment form the book of James Bennett, i think that all is fine, but the moderation comment is just for SPAM and the comments are public.. so , how ill put the comments always not public, i need that just the administrator can do public the comments.

Thanks

```
import datetime
from Paso_a_Paso.akismet import Akismet
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.comments.signals import comment_will_be_posted
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

from django.contrib.comments.moderation import CommentModerator, moderator

class NoticiaModerator(CommentModerator):
    auto_moderate_field= 'pub_date'
    moderate_after = 30
    email_notification = True


    def moderate(self, comment, content_object, request):
        already_moderated = super(NoticiaModerator,self).moderate(comment, content_object, request)
        if already_moderated:
            return True
        akismet_api = Akismet(key=settings.AKISMET_API_KEY,blog_url="http:/%s/" %Site.objects.get_current().domain)
        if akismet_api.verify_key():
            akismet_data = {'comment_type': 'comment',
                            'referrer': request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                            'user_ip': comment.ip_address,
                            'user_agent': request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']}
            return akismet_api.comment_check(smart_str(comment.comment),
                                             akismet_data,
                                             build_data=True)
        return False


moderator.register(Noticia, NoticiaModerator)
```

Answer (score 1):

probably, altering the is_public field in the moderation function should do the trick

```
comment.is_public = False
```

Comment: *know, but let me try somthing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make all comments not public, except those sent by an administrator, then why not simply do just that in your `moderate` function, e. g. something like:

```
def moderate(self, comment, content_object, request):
    if comment.user and comment.user.is_staff: #or maybe is_superuser
        return False
    return True
```

If the user who sent the comment is a staff member (or whatever other requirements), `return False` means the comment will not be moderated (e. g. `is_public` will be set to `True`), otherwise `return True` means it will be moderated (e. g. `is_public` set to `False` until somebody set it to `True` in the admin interface).